# NSManagedObjectContext giving an error asking for a ";" and I'm not sure why

Tags: ios, core-data

When in Xcode 5 I am using the code below, which is in the @interface area, to get data from my CoreData model. It is telling me that I should insert a semi-colon here,

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Below is my full code block.

```
//Get Data     
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
        id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
            context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
        }
        return context;
    }
```

Comment: What is the point of `if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)])`? If it responds the selector it will return the moc, if it doesn't it will crash.

Comment: @Abizern: No, it will return nil. That doesn't imply a crash. A lot of APIs in obj-c return nil if something does not exist. It's quite common.

Comment: @cjwirth Really? I think you'll find that this throws an exception if the object doesn't respond to the message. What the OP should be doing instead is calling `respondsToSelector:` which is frequently done before sending a message to an object that may not respond to the  message for this exact reason.

Comment: @Abizern: Ah, my apologies, I misread it. I was expecting `respondsToSelector:`. Yes, this will crash unless it is implemented and returns a non-nil value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When in Xcode 5 I am using the code below, which is in the @interface area, to get data from my CoreData model.

This is you problem, you're only supposed to but declarations in the @interface. Actual implementations go in the @implementation section.

Your interface goes

```
@interface
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext;
@end
```

In you **implementation** you put the actual method:

```
@implementation
...
//Get Data     
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
        id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
            context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
        }
        return context;
    }
...
@end
```

UPDATE:

Thanks to Abizern for noticing that there was another bug in your code: the line `[delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]` should actually be `[delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]`, because otherwise the application will crash if it *doesn't* respond to the selector.

Answer (score 0):

you have weird getter in my opinion, try ti use something like this one

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

     if (_managedObjectContext != nil)
     {
         return _managedObjectContext;
     }

     NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
     if (coordinator != nil)
     {
         _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
         [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
     }
     return _managedObjectContext;
}
```